# How to implemet Git for 3 developers on a Linux server

Tags: git, server

We are 3 computers connected to a Linux server which have all files of our proyect. We currently have some problems with overwriting files. So we would like to work 3 at te same time in the same file without overwriting problems.  We figured out that Git is our solution.

The thing is that we are working directly on the server files (so in our computer we dont have any proyect file) and we test the work in a subdomain of our server (we dont have a test enviroment in our self computer). So we are looking to change that and implement Git to merge the upgrades that we are working on independly and saving all versions of our proyect. We have some knowledge about doing this but we dont know exactly how to structure it.

We would like to keep working directly on the server but implementing Git to fix the problem.

The problem is that we dont know how to set up the directory structure that allows us to do tests each one to different versions we are working on for the same file.

The question is, how we can do to work with Git and keep all our files on our server and at the same time have the option to do tests for each file? we need to have independent directories in the server and then merge the files for the production server?

Answer (score 1):

first create a repo for the project, 
commit and push the files what is in production.
now as soon as the repo is created it has a branch called master.
So your code is in master branch, create another branch from the master branch as 
Staging, dev1, dev2 and dev3.
As soon the developer one finishes work you can pull it on staging and all good after testing push it to master.

Comment: Thanks, but you know if we can test files independently from dev branches? We would like to test our own file before merge it on the Staging branch. I dont know if you are understanding exactly what we would like to do. Basically we want to develop and test directly on our server and i dont know if we could do it in directly on dev branches. Thanks a lot.